# Select option box from my SQL number values with incremental options

Tags: php, mysql, html-select, box

Please advice how do one do the following:
I have a select option with MySQL values but with a slight twist.
I have MySQL values 3, 1, 1 on 3 different lines and need to have the select option box display a select option with the first select box displaying the option 1, 2, 3. The second line only displaying the number 1 (As its only the number 1 in the query table) and the 3rd one exactly the same. These values can change depending on the number in the MySQL. At the moment its displaying the first row as 1, 2, 3 but in 3 different tables.

Here is my code:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($sql2)) {  

for ($i = 1; $i <= $rowcount; $i++):
    ?>

    <td><select><center>
    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    </center></select></td>
    <?php
endfor;

echo "</tr>";
};
```

[adding Select BOX with end MYSQL values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTJBS.jpg)

Comment: So to break my question down: If you have numbers in your MySQL DB. I want to have incremental numbers from 1 to a max of the particular table value to be displayed in a select option box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out.
Here is the answer I was looking for:

```html
<?php
echo "<td><select>";
    for ($i=1; $i<=$rowcount; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <center><option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></center></option>
        <?php
    }
echo "</td></select>";
?>
```